# Why do I get "Session engagement user property is in the bundle without session ID." Firebase error?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-mediaplayer

My app is using firebase storage for playing songs. The app is working fine but when I check my device logs I found this error. What is the cause of this error?

[image]

Comment: That is not an error. That message comes from Google Analytics for Firebase,.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: OK, will follow this..  @Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, this is part of some automatic collected events from Firebase Analytics and not something you need to worry about. As you said yourself, your app is working fine. So this should not be a bother.

You can check here. There are some automatically collected events for `session_start` and `user_engagement`. It is most likely part of something internal.

Check more here:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484&visit_id=637598798653514539-3248286349&rd=1